# ImportError when using FastAPI with new SQLAlchemy syntax (2.0 version)

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am trying to combine FastAPI with the new version of SQLAlchemy 2.0.0 to create a new database entry when sending a JSON to the localhost URL. When I uncomment the FastAPI code, I receive the following error:

from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column, Session
ImportError: cannot import name 'DeclarativeBase' from 'sqlalchemy.orm' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/**init**.py)

However, when I comment out the FastAPI code, everything works fine, and I can add users to the database without any issues. Here's the code I'm working with:

```
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, create_engine
from typing import Optional, List
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column, Session
from fastapi import FastAPI
import json
from pydantic import BaseModel
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str]
    age: Mapped[int]
    
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///users.db")

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    user1 = User(name="Marc", age=17)
    user2 = User(name="Martha", age=20)
    
    session.add(user1)
    session.add(user2)
    
    session.commit()
    


# class AddUser(BaseModel):
#     name: str
#     age: str
    

# @app.post("/users/")
# async def post_user(add_user: AddUser):
#     with Session(engine) as session:
#         user = User(name=add_user.name, age=add_user.age)
#         session.add(user)
#         session.commit()
        
#     return json.dumps({"name": user.name, "age": user.age})
```

I have tried updating FastAPI and SQLAlchemy to the latest versions, but the issue persists. When I comment out the fastapi code as shown above everythin works and I am able to create a database and add the users.

How can I resolve this ImportError when using FastAPI with the new SQLAlchemy syntax? Are there any known compatibility issues between FastAPI and the new SQLAlchemy version?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: You haven't commented out FastAPI code though? What python and sqlalchemy versions are you running?

Comment: I coppied my code over wrong. I now corrected it so that it looks the same as in my code edditor. I am running python 3.11.3, SQLalchemy 2.0.11 fastapi 0.95.1 and uvicorn 0.21.1